# How to get started developing an OPC Xi (.NET 3.0 WCF Services) Server (Service)

Tags: .net, wcf, opc

I would like to implement an OPC Server using the latest standard version: `OPC Xi`.
My purpose is not providing a service for real usage, I just would like to develop a finctional server returning data from sensors of a certain industrial station (non existing: finctional).

The main purpose is to create a server for academic purposes, in order to let students and others take advantage of this free server to make practice with OPC calls and the OPC standard.

Well, I just downloaded `OPC .NET 3.0 (WCF) Contracts and ServerBase [1.20.4]` from OPCFoundation web site.

The zip contains a Visual Studio 2008 solution with several projects.

Well, I am enough skilled with WCF services, so I expect I just need to implement some interfaces right???

In the solution there is a project called `Xi Contracts VS2008`. There, I can find these interfaces (all marked as `ServiceContract`):

- `ICallback` service contract interface.
- `IPoll` service contract interface.
- `IRead` service contract interface.
- `IResourceManagement` service contract interface.
- `IRestRead` service contract interface.
- `IServerDiscovery` service contract interface.
- `IWrite` service contract interface.

I expect these to be the ones to be implemented in my web service right???

Another question: there is also a project called `Xi Server Base VS2008`, what is it for???

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OPC Training Institute has these [getting started tutorials](http://www.opcti.com/download-opc-xi-source-code.aspx) for working with OPC Xi (which by the way has been renamed to OPC .NET 3.0)

The future of OPC .NET 3.0 is very murky. The OPC Foundation seems to downplay the fact that it even exists. The OPC Foundation's position is that OPC UA is the way of the future as outlined in this [discussion](http://www.opcfoundation.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=14103).